# Reading config file doesn't work on another computer

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, windows

I am making windows application in c#.I made one application in .NET framework 3.5 and i am using windows vista.When i am making build of that application and try to run on other machine having windows 7,its not working.The targeted machine shows .NET framework 4.0 client profile in control panel.This problem comes whenever i am trying to read some value from CONFIG file.if i dont use config file then my application runs but i have to use config file.
For checking framework problem I made one simple application in which i am trying to read config file values on button click as   `MessageBox.Show(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FlagForArchiving"].ToString());`
but i am getting error as

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at TestFramework.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.239 (RTMGDR.030319-2300)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
TestFramework
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/mvi/AppData/Local/Temp/Temp1_test.zip/Release/TestFramework.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.235 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.236 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.233 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Please help me to solve my problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you copy your config file to the other machine? What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you write exact error log, so that we can investigate?

Comment: @zmbq: is there need of separate copy config file to other machine after making build of that application? My config file has some values as                                               <appSettings>
    <add key="FlagForArchiving" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>                                                        And whenever i am trying to run my application its giving error as FileNotFoundException

Comment: Yes, you need to copy your config file to the other machine. Check @Otiel's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileNotFoundException` means that the config file is not present in your app folder. Make sure the config file is deployed when you publish the application.

Yes, you need to have a config file on each machine where your app is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of directory accesses. Run your application via administrator to guarantee access.

Answer (score 0):

Change the profile to ".NET Framework 3.5". The ".NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile" has a couple of limitations and will not offer all assemblies you might need.

Comment: Thanks but my target machine has windows 7 and i think in windows 7 there is already .NET framework 3.5 installed.

Comment: @Dany But you said, that the Windows 7 machine shows the .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile in control panel. That might not contain the parts you need when you build you application with ".NET Framework 3.5" profile.

Comment: Ya its showing only .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile in control panel but not showing .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: @Dany So maybe the wrong .NET Framework is installed on that machine.